# Proof verification for proof of continuity on some bounded subset of R

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

So, I'm trying to prove that if $A\subseteq R$ is bounded and $f$ is a continuous function,then $f(A)$ is bounded.

My attempt: Suppose $f(A)$ is not bounded, then there exists an $x$ such that $|f(x)|>M$

Also, $f$ is given to be continuous on $A$. So $f$ is continuous at $c\in A$  as well. Then by definition of continuity, for $M=\epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $|(x-c)|<\delta$ $\implies$ $|f(x)-f(c)|<M$ $\forall x\in A$

Now, $|f(x)-f(c)|\leq |f(x)|+|f(c)|<M$

This implies $|f(x)|<M-f(c)$ which is a contradiction. Hence $f$ is bounded. Is this outline correct? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your formalization of "not bounded" is wrong. Bounded is: $\exists M\,\forall x\, |f(x)|\le M$, and you want to negate this. -- Also, why should $|f(x)|+|f(c)|$ be $<M$?

Comment: Also, is $f$ defined on $A$ only or on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I don't understand, what is wrong with definition of not bounded function? Should it be like for all $M\in N$ there exists $x\in A $ such that $|f(x)|>M$?

Comment: What about $A = (0,1)$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: Yeah@ infinity_hunter. Thanks. It was actually a mcq type question in which the function  defined as $f:R\mapsto R$ was given to be continuous. And the correct answer given was : f(A) is bounded for all bounded subset $A$ of $R$. I think I got it wrong. It may have something to do with compactness.

Comment: @Koro. Thanks, I now know it isn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is bounded then $\overline{A}$ is compact and since $f$ is continuous then $f(\overline{A} )$ is compact. So since $f(A)\subset f(\overline{A} )$ therefore $f(A)$ is bounded as a subset of compact set.

Comment: Thank you so much! Here A bar stands for closure of A right?

Comment: Yes, it stand for closure.